# How to regroup nested select?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this kind of request with cumulative sums (this is a simplify example)

```
INSERT INTO DEMO (a,b,c,d,e)
  SELECT 
    DATA.a,
    NVL((SELECT SUM r2.x FROM EXAMPLE r2 WHERE r2.a = r1.a AND r2.i <= r1.i),0),
    DATA.c,
    NVL((SELECT SUM r2.y FROM EXAMPLE r2 WHERE r2.a = r1.a AND r2.i <= r1.i),0),
    DATA.e
  FROM
    DATA
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EXAMPLE r1 ON DATA.a = r1.a
```

This request works but is incredibly slow. Since both the nested select looks the same, I wanted to regroup them. Something like

```
SELECT SUM r2.x, SUM r2.y FROM EXAMPLE r2 WHERE r2.a = r1.a AND r2.i <= r1.i
```

but I can not successfully achieve this. How can I do it ?

I tried both

```
INSERT INTO DEMO (a,c,e,b,d)
  SELECT 
    DATA.a,
    DATA.c,
    DATA.e
    (SELECT SUM r2.x, SUM r2.y FROM EXAMPLE r2 WHERE r2.a = r1.a AND r2.i <= r1.i)
  FROM DATA
  LEFT OUTER JOIN EXAMPLE r1
    ON DATA.a = r1.a
```

and

```
INSERT INTO DEMO (a,c,e,b,d)
  SELECT 
    DATA.a,
    DATA.c,
    DATA.e
  FROM DATA
  LEFT OUTER JOIN EXAMPLE r1
    ON DATA.a = r1.a
  UNION
  SELECT
    (SELECT SUM r2.x, SUM r2.y FROM EXAMPLE r2 WHERE r2.a = r1.a AND r2.i <= r1.i)
  FROM DATA
  LEFT OUTER JOIN EXAMPLE r1
    ON DATA.a = r1.a
```

Comment: A decent modern query optimizer (such as Oracle's) would identify the re-use of the expression and so not evaluate it twice, so I think your performance issues lie elsewhere. Have you examined the Execution Plan to see the relative costing of each component of the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cumulative sums (running totals) computed with self joins are usually slow, because for every record all matching former records must be read again.

Better use the analytic function SUM instead:

```
INSERT INTO DEMO (a,b,c,d,e)
  SELECT 
    DATA.a,
    NVL( SUM(x) OVER (PARTITION BY r1.a ORDER BY r1.i
                      RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) , 0),
    DATA.c,
    NVL( SUM(y) OVER (PARTITION BY r1.a ORDER BY r1.i
                      RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) , 0),
    DATA.e
  FROM DATA
  LEFT OUTER JOIN EXAMPLE r1
    ON DATA.a = r1.a
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can now run it in a reasonable time ;)